# Center of mass of ellipsoid with variable density

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I wanted to impose that the center of mass of the ellipsoid $(x/a)^2+(y/b)^2+(z/(h/2))^2=1$ would be a 56% of its height, $h$, namely, $Z_{CM}=(6/100)h$ and so this can only be achieved by coming up with a variable density for it, particularly, I thought of one which only varies depending on $z$ of the form $\rho (z)=\rho_o+A\cos(\alpha z+\Phi)$. Now, what I wanted to ask was whether these two limits of integration yield the same result, and if not, which one should I apply?:

$$Z_{CM}=\dfrac{\displaystyle ab\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{-\frac{h}{2}}^{\frac{h}{2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{2z}{h}\right)^2}} z\rho (z)r dr dz d\theta}{\displaystyle ab\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{-\frac{h}{2}}^{\frac{h}{2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{2z}{h}\right)^2}} \rho (z)r dr dz d\theta}$$

$$Z_{CM}=\dfrac{\displaystyle ab\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{-\frac{h}{2}\sqrt{1-r^2}}^{\frac{h}{2}\sqrt{1-r^2}} z\rho (z)r dz dr d\theta}{\displaystyle ab\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{-\frac{h}{2}\sqrt{1-r^2}}^{\frac{h}{2}\sqrt{1-r^2}} \rho (z)r dz dr d\theta}$$

I think the last one gives me 0 when I plug it in WolframAlpha because of the symmetric limits for $z$ whilst the one on top doesn't. That's why I asked.